# How to delete attachments/images from an email without deleting the email itself (Gmail)?

Tags: gmail, email, images, backup, gmail-attachments

I've received a bunch of emails with large attachments and images.  I want to keep the emails ***(including their headers)*** for my records, but I don't want the attachments and images using up my allotment of storage on Google's servers.  I also want to keep my backups small, and they add unneeded bulk to my backup files.

In Gmail, how can one delete attachments/images from emails without deleting the email itself?

To keep this QA generic enough to help everyone, answers addressing sent and/or received emails are fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Unattach](https://unattach.app/) web application to strip attachments and/or resize images.

With a monthly limit of 30 e-mail messages, it's free. For $10 per year, there's no limit.